# Amazon Sqs FIFO queue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I can't send message to a FIFO queue using the PHP SDK v2.7.16.

I get an exception: "The request must contain the parameter MessageGroupId," even though I am passing a valid `MessageGroupId` argument.

```
 public function sendMessage($queueUrl,$messageBody)
 {
   $this->client->sendMessage(array(
   'QueueUrl'    => $queueUrl,
   'MessageBody' => $messageBody,
   'MessageGroupId'=>'messagegroupid1000',
   'MessageDeduplicationID'=>'messagededuplicationid1000'));
 }
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: I assume you are using an AWS SDK, but if so, what version and language is it?  This parameter may not be correctly handled in the version you are using, if it predates the existence of FIFO queues.

Comment: aws sdk: php ,  v 2.7.16

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Support for SQS FIFO queues was apparently introduced in version 3.19.28 (2016-11-17) of the AWS SDK for PHP.

See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/migration.html

Comment: @СергейАнтонец since you are new, I'll mention -- don't forget to click the checkbox to accept the answer if it solves the problem.